# Metrizability of weak * topology of finite dimensional banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence

$X$ is a $K$-linear Banach space. $(X^*,\tau_{w^*})$ is metrizable $\iff$ X is Finite Dimensional.

---

A completely unrelated question:

What is the meaning of "the topology $\sigma(X,X^*)$"?

Comment: I understand that if $X$ is finite dimensional then the strong topology is equal to the weak* topology. Then $(X^*,\tau_{w^*})$ should be metrizable.

Comment: The topology $\sigma(X,X^*)$ is the coarsest topology on $X$, such that the functionals in $X^*$ are continuous, i.e., if $X$ is a normed linear space, this is the weak topology. Similarly, $\sigma(X^*,X)$ is the weak-$*$ topology on $X^*$.

Comment: Is the above reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct for $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: Shouldn't the weak * topology on $X^*$ be $\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$?

Comment: No, $\sigma(X^*,X^{**})$ is the weak topology on $X^*$. The weak-$*$ topology is generated by the functionals from $X$.

Comment: Maybe important: the weak-$*$ topology is the (subset of the) product topology.